# List comprehension/ or any other method to compute summation of 2 variables

Tags: python, list, math, list-comprehension

I wanted to compute the below equation but using list comprehension in Python. How would I be able to do so?

Below is the equation:-

[image]

Below are the values of x,y and n-

```
x=54
y=12
n= Varies from range (1,5)
```

Comment: Given `x` and `y` are both constants, this just evaluates to `n * (x - y)**2`. Why do you want to use a comprehension?

Comment: Yes, why would you want to use list comprehensions ?

Comment: I have mentioned the same in the comments

Comment: Aside from the math question - do you know how to write list comprehensions *at all*? What actually is the *source of difficulty* here?

Comment: A *generator expression*, used with `sum`, is reasonable, though, assuming `x` and/or `y` actually vary with `i` in some way.

Comment: `sum((x[i]-y[i])**2 for i in range(1,5))`, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like below:

```
x=54
y=12
n=5    
print(sum([(x - y) ** 2 for _ in range(n)]))
```

idea is, the inner list comprehension provides a list of (x - y) ^ 2 'n' times and then we apply the sum() on the returned list.

To understand better, try the below statement and then add the sum() to it

```
print([(x - y) ** 2 for _ in range(n)])
```